# Visitor Log takes input then displays new message

Tags: php

When the user visits the Visitor Log page, they should be able to see a prompt asking them to enter their name.
Upon submitting the form, the same page should display a completely different message welcoming the user to the webpage.
When the user refreshes the page, the process starts over.

This is what I have tried so far, it works but I still don't understand who I would display a whole new message after the input also when I refresh it does not clear the input I have to go to the website again for it to restart.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="store.css">

       <?php include 'navbar.php';?>

    </style>-->
        <title>Visitor Log</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        </head>

        <body class="background-body-color ">


        <div class="centered-container borderColor">

            <h1 id="example-id-name" class=" centered-text sansSerif-text ">Visitor Log</h1>



    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<p2 id="example-id-name" class="centered-text "><center>Please enter your name<center></p>
<p><span class="error"></span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php

echo $name;
echo "<br>";

?>

  </div>
        <script src ="scripts/test.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script src = "scripts/jquery_test.js"></script>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

All of the PHP logic should be on store_visitor_log.php. At no point should the user be on any other page during this process.
The message before submitting the form should be completely different from the message after submitting the form. This will require me to use conditional statements.
You must only use PHP to complete this task.

[this is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwhD3.png)
[after entering the name it must change to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxI3.png)

Comment: Ok, so where is the HTML for this Welcome page? Or is that what you want us to write

Comment: There is no welcome page, all php code is on my home page. This code works on returning the name entered what I need help on is displaying a completely different message after it is entered. So it says Please enter name then after entering the name instead of just displaying the input it should display welcome name entered and remove the phrase please enter name.

Comment: I refer to this sentence in your question ___Upon submitting the form, the same page should display a completely different message welcoming the user to the webpage___

Comment: I added some images to clarify that question sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated the code to the complete code in a .php file